Haskell ForeignPtr finalizer with two environments
The problem is FFI wrapping a C-Type that requires two environment variables for initialization and de-allocation with a ForeignPtr 
More concretely I want to wrap
void gr_mpoly_init(gr_mpoly_t A, const mpoly_ctx_t mctx, gr_ctx_t cctx)
and
void gr_mpoly_clear(gr_mpoly_t A, const mpoly_ctx_t mctx, gr_ctx_t cctx)
for a Haskell type GRMPoly ... .
So the question is how to define something like
addForeignPtrFinalizerEnv2 myfinalizer mypointer env1 env2
I looked at the source of of addForeignPtrFinalizerEnv in ForeignPtr.ForeignPtr but that seems to require an understanding of the underlying "magic" (include #).
So what are "elegant" alternatives?
The simplest solution I could come up with was defining a container for the two pointers including the extra infrastructure for allocating and deallocation and wrapping in Haskell.
I would expect a simpler, more elegant solution ...

Perhaps you could write a small C wrapper function which combines the two environments.
typedef struct {
    mpoly_ctx_t mpoly_ctx;
    gr_ctx_t gr_ctx;
} *mpoly_gr_ctx_t;

void combined_gr_mpoly_clear(mpoly_gr_ctx_t ctx, gr_mpoly_t A) {
    gr_mpoly_clear(A, ctx->mpoly_ctx, ctx->gr_ctx);
}

I've also swapped the argument order to better match the order that FinalizerEnvPtrs expect their arguments.
It's been a while since I've done C; please forgive me if I've misremembered some of the syntax. If I've misremembered so badly that the idea is unclear, leave me a comment and I'll try to expand a bit more in English.

Actually, on second read of the question, it seems you may have come up with this idea yourself, too, but didn't like it. Rest assured that I think it is the simplest and most elegant solution available to you, so well done for coming up with it!
